# A word for "relayable"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

We have a system in the app we are building whereby admin users can be invited to events and they, in turn, can invite users under their control to the same event. If that's allowed for any particular event we say that an event is "relayable" but we're not convinced thats either a real word or indeed a good word for the job.

What's an alternative word for this idea?

Comment: To `relay` means to receive and pass on. If the invitation is relayed, then the person relaying no longer has it. I don't think you want to imply that.

Comment: Would cascade suffice - succession of stages or operations or processes or units (or information).

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction We often speak of relaying a message. When the thing being relayed is information, passing it on doesn't cause the relayer to lose it.

Comment: @Barmar: Nice catch. But can invitations be relayed too?

Comment: Sure. If someone invites you and says "pass this on to anyone I've missed", that's relaying the invitation.

Comment: You can relay or extend the invitation, but not the event. I'd call the invitation "extensible"

Answer (score 2):

You could call the invites ***[transferable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transferable)*** or ***[shareable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shareable)***, maybe even ***[extendable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extendable)***.

Note that my suggestions refer to the *invitation*, rather than the *events*.